# WordPress Database Query works in phpMyAdmin but not in the code

Tags: database, query, mysql, wpdb

I have a simple SQL query: `SELECT * FROM test_table__csv_import_temp_joblist WHERE url ='https://www.example.com'`

In phpMyAdmin, it works well and returns a result.
In WP it returns nothing:

```
$sql        = "SELECT * FROM test_table__csv_import_temp_joblist WHERE url ='https://www.example.com'";
$res        = $wpdb->query( $sql );
```

What is the issue with my query?

`$wpdb->last_query` returns the right query.
`$wpdb->last_error` returns nothing.

Many Thanks

Comment: Are you certain that this table is in the same database as the one WordPress is using?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you use `query` method of `wpdb` and if you read it’s docs:

> The query function allows you to execute any SQL query on the WordPress database. It is best used when there is a need for specific, custom, or otherwise complex SQL queries. For more basic queries, such as selecting information from a table, see the other `wpdb` functions above such as `get_results, get_var, get_row or get_col`.
>
> **query**  (string) The SQL query you wish to execute. This function
>   returns an integer value indicating the number of rows
>   affected/selected for `SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE`, etc. For `CREATE`,
>   `ALTER, TRUNCATE` and `DROP SQL` statements, (which affect whole tables
>   instead of specific rows) this function returns TRUE on success. If a
>   MySQL error is encountered, the function will return FALSE. Note that
>   since both 0 and FALSE may be returned for row queries, you should be
>   careful when checking the return value. Use the identity operator
>   (`===`) to check for errors (e.g., `false === $result`), and whether any
>   rows were affected (e.g., `0 === $result`).

You’ll see that it’s not what you want.

If you want to get results of the query, you should use `get_results` method:

$res = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );